# SMTLIB / z3 / stp: Meaning of underscore?

Tags: z3, smt

I don't understand the meaning of the underscore, e.g. in these (unrelated) expressions

[[source](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorialcontent/guide)]

```
(display (_ bv20 8))
(declare-const x (_ BitVec 64))
```

or this:

```
(declare-fun a () (Array (_ BitVec 32) (_ BitVec 7)))
```

[[source](http://stp.github.io/smt-input-language/)]

What does the "`_`" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [§3.3 Identifiers](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.5-r2015-06-28.pdf) section of the SMTLIB manual, `(_ <symbol> <index>+)` is a way to define *indexed identifiers*. I think that this is equivalent to encoding information inside identifiers in other languages, such as `int_64`, except that the data has a more explicit structure.